# 2D array, output x and y axes on grid

Tags: c++

I am trying to output my array into a 2D grid with the columns labelled from 1 through 5, but I am stuck on arranging j in order to do so

```
    char array[5][5];

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
      for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
      {
        array[i][j] = 'O';
      }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
      out << i + 1 << "  ";
      for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
      {
        out << array[i][j] << "  ";
      }
      out << endl;
    }
```

Current Output:

> ```
> 1  O  O  O  O  O  
> 2  O  O  O  O  O  
> 3  O  O  O  O  O  
> 4  O  O  O  O  O  
> 5  O  O  O  O  O
> ```

Desired Output:

> ```
>    1  2  3  4  5  
> 1  O  O  O  O  O  
> 2  O  O  O  O  O  
> 3  O  O  O  O  O  
> 4  O  O  O  O  O  
> 5  O  O  O  O  O
> ```

Thank you.

Comment: You never print first row with column captions... Also real output will actually print indexes starting from `0`. This does not match "Current output".

Comment: Are you asking how to print the first row?

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask how to print the first row with those numbers shown in the desired output, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @J.Doe How didn't you know how to do this? You obviously know how to print things so why can't you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out << "   ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    out << i << "  ";
out << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    out << i << "  ";
    for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    {
        out << array[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    out << endl;
}
```

Print the first line, and then print the rest.

Comment: This was the exact direction I was headed in, I figured that I would need to make another loop to output the j values, otherwise I would get numbers 1-5 before/after every "O" since it's in a loop. It compiles fine and works correctly now, thank you for the help.

Comment: If it matters, when I try compiling it, windows seems to detect my file as a virus, but when I try putting that code under a function to display the array, the virus detection seemed to stop. Not sure why, but it does not alter my output. It is specifically the out << "  "; part, since I am working with files rather than cin/cout.

Comment: I've never had a problem with anti virus and development myself. Could depend on the compiler, the compile options and the antivirus itself.
Better ask google if you want to find out more :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
int n = 5;
int i = 1;

cout << "  ";
for (; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << i << "  ";
}
cout << n << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop to print the title between the two existing ones:

```
// Print title
cout << "   ";
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    cout << i << "  ";
}
cout << endl;
```